# Promoting posts of a specific taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a CPT named "products". It has different categories (cars, mobile, home, beauty etc.)

I want to create another one and name it `promoted` and I want posts of this category to be listed at top of others.

I have a `pre_get_posts` hook right now and it is as follow:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    // Bail if we are on an admin page or if this is not the main query
    if (    is_admin()
         || !$q->is_main_query() 
    )
        return;

    // Only targets the product-category tax pages
    if ( $q->is_tax( 'product-category' ) ) { 
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }

    if ( $q->is_home() ) {
        // Set posts_per_page 
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', get_option( 'zens_home_count' ) );
        // Set custom post type 
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'products' );
        // Set random ordering 
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }       
});
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Would you want them to act like sticky posts

Comment: @PieterGoosen What would be the difference?

Comment: It is quite easy to achieve that, but then you would look at say 20 posts on page one, 10 from the selected term and then 10 normal from the query and just 10 normal posts on paged pages

Comment: @PieterGoosen Remember how you gave me codes for function.php for randomizing? Will sticky posts still be affected by that? That is my intention.

Comment: What we can do is, we remove all posts from the desired term from the main query. We then re-inject those posts randomly before the normal posts on page 1

Comment: @PieterGoosen Would it cause unnecessary waste of speed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103015/discussion-between-pieter-goosen-and-sarpsta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best possible way is to remove "vip" posts completely from the main query and then adding them back on top of the loop with either a custom query or via the `the_posts` filter.

Lets remove the "vip" posts (*ID `27`*) from the main query on the home page and custom post type archive pages. I will merge everything into one action to keep the code in one place

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( \WP_Query $q )
{
    // Bail if we are on an admin page or if this is not the main query
    if ( is_admin() )
        return;

    if (  !$q->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only targets the product-category tax pages
    if ( $q->is_tax( 'product-category' ) ) { 
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }

    if ( $q->is_home() ) {
        // Set posts_per_page 
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', get_option( 'zens_home_count' ) );
        // Set custom post type 
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'products' );
        // Set random ordering 
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }   

    if (    $q->is_home()
         || $q->is_post_type_archive( 'products' )
         || $q->is_tax( 'product-category' )
    ) {
        // Bail on the vip page
        if ( !$q->is_tax( 'product-category', 'vip' ) ) { // Make sure about slug
            $tax_query = [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
                    'terms'    => 27,
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ]
            ];
            $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
});
```

Now we can add those posts back

### OPTION 1

Via the `the_posts` filter

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() )
         return $posts;

    if ( !$q->is_main_query() )// Only target the main query
        return $posts;

    if (    !$q->is_paged()      // Only target the first page
         && (    $q->is_home()   // Only target the home page OR
              || $q->is_post_type_archive( 'products' )  // Only target the post type archive page OR
              || $q->is_tax( 'product-category' )        // Only target the taxonomy archive page AND
            )
    ) {
        // Bail on vip tax pages
        if ( $q->is_tax( 'product-category', 'vip' ) )
            return $posts;

        // Lets get all vip posts
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'      => 'products',
            'orderby'        => 'rand', // Order these posts randomly
            'tax_query'      => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
                    'terms'    => 27
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $vip_posts = get_posts( $args );

        // Make sure we have vip posts, if not, we bail
        if ( !$vip_posts )
            return $posts;

        // OK, we have vip posts, lets add them infront of the loop
        $posts = array_merge( $vip_posts, $posts );
    }

    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

For this, to keep vip ads seperate, we can run the loop once to only display vip ads, rewind the loop and then rerun it again to display only normal ads

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    // Run the loop to display vip ads
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

            if ( has_term( 27, 'product-category' ) ) {
                // Add your markup and stuff here for vip ads
            }
    } // end our vip ads loop

    rewind_posts(); // Set the counter back to 1 so we can rerun the loop

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

            if ( !has_term( 27, 'product-category' ) ) {
                // Your normal markup to display all ads
            }
    }
}
```

### OPTION 2

Via a custom query

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'orderby'        => 'rand', // Order these posts randomly
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
            'terms'    => 27
        ]
    ]
];
$vip_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

// Run the loop
if ( $vip_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $vip_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $vip_posts->the_post();

        // Display what you want in your loop like
        the_title();
        echo '</br>';

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly except for one very tiny problem. It creates a duplicate for each post of vip category on admin page.

Comment: I have time now to talk quickly, let me know then we use the same room as last night

Comment: How about evening then? I have stood up all night and gotta go to school now

Comment: I have also addd a possible solution for a loop if you use option 1

Comment: no problem. It is 7:30 am here, I will available at 18:00 tonight. Enjoy ;-)